# How to remove large indentation in TextMeshPro?

Tags: unity

When I changed the center text with the size tag, the line height remained the same.

[image]

After I used the tag to resize:
[image]

How do I remove indentation?

Comment: Have you tried putting the line breaks inside your size change tags, rather than outside of them?

Comment: @DMGregory, It works, thank you very much.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please share your solution as an Answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set line breaks inside tags

```
UPTEXT<size=14>  
CENTERTEXT 
</size>DOWNTEXT
```

or

```
UPTEXT<size=14>\nCENTERTEXT\n</size>DOWNTEXT
```